# How implements agregation function SUM in QueryDsl

Tags: spring, querydsl, netflix-dgs

Description of my Task:
I am used Query Dsl for fetch my data .
I can't find any solution to use aggregation function such SUM in queryDsl.
my objectif is return
Map<String(key),SUM(col2)> query=new JPAQUERY()
any solution please